# My read-only user is able to write

Tags: mongodb

I'm using MongoDB 3.0.7. I have a database called `bravegoat` and a read-only user called `bravegoat-r`.

I connect via shell:

```
mongo localhost:27017/bravegoat -u bravegoat-r -p mypassword
```

I switch to my database:

```
use bravegoat;
```

And I run:

```
db.runCommand({connectionStatus : 1})
```

Which outputs:

```
{
        "authInfo" : {
                "authenticatedUsers" : [
                        {
                                "user" : "bravegoat-r",
                                "db" : "bravegoat"
                        }
                ],
                "authenticatedUserRoles" : [
                        {
                                "role" : "read",
                                "db" : "bravegoat"
                        }
                ]
        },
        "ok" : 1
}
```

Only `read` role, so it looks fine, but when I invoke `.save()`, my user **can insert data**. I've read few pages about creating read-only users and I'm not able to see my problem. I'm starting to think it might be a bug in my version.

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing. Did you get anywhere with this?

Comment: Not yet. Is not important for me right now, but I'd like to fix it. I will try with a newer version or platform.

Comment: I have the same problem too... My user can write to the database although I configured it as a read only user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to enable client access control by doing the following:

1. Edit the `/etc/mongod.conf` file
2. Add the following lines

`security:
    authorization: enabled`

3. Restart MongoDB:

`sudo service mongodb restart`